Issue with Azure DevOps Dynamic Comment to GitHub and Exit Status 1
I have an pipeline in Azure DevOps that lints my Ansible code to catch errors before it is merged.
While we are using required status checks in GitHub, I would like any lint errors to be added back as a comment.
I am running into two issues.
#1 - Cannot Set Comment
    - task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: ${{ parameters.dispName }}
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      set -euo pipefail
      export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
      export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
      export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id | xargs)
      export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
      export TF_CLI_ARGS="-no-color"
      echo $PATH     
      ansible --version
      ansible-lint --version
      ansible-lint ${{ parameters.command }} 2>&1 | tee ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log
      temp=(grep -A 2 Error  ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log)
      if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
      

- template: comment.yaml
  parameters:
    comment: $temp

comment.yml
---

parameters:
- name: comment
  type: string


steps:

- task: GitHubComment@0 
  displayName: 'Add github comment'
  inputs:
    pull-requests: write
    gitHubConnection: 'github-comment'
    repositoryName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
    comment: ${{ parameters.comment }}
      

This comment.yaml file does work if I just pass in a static comment, like 'test'.
#2 - Pipeline exits with Status Code 2
If I change the comment to just a static comment, to get around the above issue, the pipeline now exits with a Status Code 2, not a Status Code 1, like I am setting here:
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit 1; fi

With an exist code of 2, GitHub does not mark the pipeline as failed in the event of a lint error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is my updated code:
---
parameters:
- name: serviceConnectionName
  type: string
- name: command
  type: string
- name: dispName
  type: string
- name: logFile
  type: string

steps:

- template: init-github.yaml
- template: install-ansible-lint.yaml

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: ${{ parameters.dispName }}
  inputs:
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      set -euo pipefail
      export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
      export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
      export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id | xargs)
      export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
      export TF_CLI_ARGS="-no-color"
      echo $PATH     
      ansible --version
      ansible-lint --version
      ansible-lint ${{ parameters.command }} 2>&1 | tee ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log
      error=$(grep -A 2 Error ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log)    
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Comment]$error"

- template: comment.yaml
  parameters:
    comment: $(Comment)

comment.yaml file
---
    parameters:
    - name: comment
      type: string


    steps:
    
    - task: GitHubComment@0 
      displayName: 'Add github comment'
      inputs:
        pull-requests: write
        gitHubConnection: 'github-comment'
        repositoryName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
        comment: ${{ parameters.comment }}
    
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Fail Pipeline If Error
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          if [ -n "${{ parameters.comment }}" ]; then
            echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"
          fi



So @Wade zhou pointed me in the right direction. It seems that the variable was too big perhaps to pass between steps, so I solved it this way.
Main Pipeline:
---
pr:
  autoCancel: true
  drafts: true
  branches:
    include:
    - p0
  paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md
    - RELEASE_NOTES.md
    - .azuredevops/*
    - doc/*    
    
trigger: none


pool: Lottery Production Pool

variables:
- name: serviceConnectionName
  value: gcg-network-production

stages:
- stage: check
  jobs:
  - job: Check
    steps:
    - template: templates/run-ansible-lint.yaml
      parameters:
        serviceConnectionName: ${{ variables.serviceConnectionName }}
        logFile: ansible-lint
        dispName: Run ansible-lint
        command: -r lint/ group_vars/*.* host_vars/*.*
    - template: templates/comment.yaml
      parameters:
        dispName: Add Comments to PR

Lint template:
---
parameters:
- name: serviceConnectionName
  type: string
- name: command
  type: string
- name: dispName
  type: string
- name: logFile
  type: string
steps:
- template: init-github.yaml
- template: install-ansible-lint.yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: ${{ parameters.dispName }}
  inputs:
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    continueOnError: true
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      set -euo pipefail
      export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
      export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
      export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id | xargs)
      export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
      export TF_CLI_ARGS="-no-color"
      echo $PATH     
      ansible --version
      ansible-lint --version
      ansible-lint ${{ parameters.command }} 2>&1 | tee ansible-lint.log

Comment Template
---
    steps:

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Extract Comment
      condition: always()
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          comment=$(sed -z 's/\n/\%0D%0A/g' ansible-lint.log)
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Comment]$comment"

    - task: GitHubComment@0 
      displayName: 'Add github comment'
      condition: always()
      inputs:
        pull-requests: write
        gitHubConnection: 'github-comment'
        repositoryName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
        comment: "$(Comment)"

The comment in GitHub:


Glad to know it's resolved! And sorry for late response due to weekend. Yes, devops variables doesn't support multiple lines.  The trick is to use sed to convert all the newline characters in the ansible-lint.log file. Thanks for yoru sharing! Happy coding!

Local variable temp in your AzureCLI@2 task is not available in future tasks.
You need to add a variable using the task.setvariable logging command, so that the following tasks can use the variable using macro syntax $(myVar). The variable will only be available to tasks in the same job by default.
Example:
steps:
  - script: |
      GIT_COMMENT="foobar"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Comment]$GIT_COMMENT"
    displayName: 'Set pipeline variable: Comment'
  
  - script: |
      echo "Git comment: $(Comment)"
    displayName: 'Print pipeline variable: Comment'

See Set variables in scripts

As @RuiJarimba mentioned, you need to add task.setvariable logging command so that you can use $(temp) in the next task. In addition, please add $ for temp value:temp=$(grep -A 2 Failed  ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log).
For the exit code, you can evaluate the $(temp) content, if it's not empty, use echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]" to set the task as fail, so that it will return failed at gihub status check.
Use PR trigger as GitHubComment@0 will automatically detect the PR id in my testing pipeline:
trigger: none

pr: 
 branches:
   include:
     - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
  - name: logFile
    default: ansible-lint-log
  - name: command
    default: main.yml


steps:
- script: sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y ansible
  displayName: 'Install Ansible'

- script: pip install ansible-lint
  displayName: 'Install Ansible Lint'

- script: |
    ansible --version
    ansible-lint --version
  displayName: 'Check Ansible and Ansible Lint versions'

- script: |
    ansible-lint ${{ parameters.command }} 2>&1 | tee ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log
    temp=$(grep -A 2 Failed  ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log)    # add $ for temp

    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Comment]$temp"
    #if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
  displayName: 'Lint Ansible playbook and check for errors'


- template: comment.yaml
  parameters:
    comment: $(Comment)

My template yaml：
parameters:
- name: comment
  type: string


steps:
- task: GitHubComment@0 
  displayName: 'Add github comment'
  inputs:
    pull-requests: write
    gitHubConnection: 'GithubConn1'
    repositoryName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
    comment: '${{ parameters.comment }}'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: fail the task if there is an error
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      if [ -n "${{ parameters.comment }}" ]; then
        echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"
      fi

Check PR, the comment added, and status check as failed:


Thanks for the super detailed answer!

You're welcome! You can follow the sample pipeline(Filter for Error based on your log) for a check, glad to help. :)

So I tried this and am running into issues.
The lint task fails (as expected) but it does not continue on with the other steps. If I add continueonerror: true, it continues but the pipeline never fails.
If the comment does get put in, it is just $(Commnet).
I updated it above to show new code. @wade zhou

Yes, you need to use continueonerror: true to continue to next task, but make sure the error is stored into the log file. The command ansible-lint ${{ parameters.command }} 2>&1 | tee ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log should already redirect both the standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr) to the log file, regardless of whether the ansible-lint command succeeds or fails. But if you’re finding that this isn’t working as expected, please try with ansible-lint ${{ parameters.command }} > ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log 2>&1

so the issue is around this:
'      ansible-lint ${{ parameters.command }} 2>&1 | tee ${{ parameters.logFile }}.log '
I tried your change and it did not matter. Without it in this structure the output does not seem to be sent to the log file, but with it like this continueOnError seems to be ignored.
'   scriptType: bash'
'   scriptLocation: inlineScript'
'   continueOnError: true'
It will not continue on the error at all.

So the issue is actually here temp=$(cat ansible-lint.log) and echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Comment]$temp"
For some reason the temp appears to be empty even when I know that the log should have sometihng.
